What is the production rule for "depend_expr" in SCADE EBNF?
During studying Scade EBNF definition, there is a snippet like the following
expr ::= 
  ... 
  | depend_expr 

But the production rule for "depend_expr" can not be found in the grammar. What is the production for "depend_expr"? Or is "depend_expr" deprecated?
